# 'chmod' shows error: "chmod' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to connect to an instance (or something like that) using aws's ec2 thing. I had to change the permissions of a .pem file with the command 'chmod 400 grabage' it throws an error (**chmod' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.**) Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: That's a Windows error message, but `chmod` is a Unix command, so potentially not appropriate in your exact scenario.  Perhaps backing up a step is appropriate... you need to change the permissions on the private key in order to solve what problem, specifically?

Comment: Well, in order to connect to the ec2 instance I made, I have to change the permissions of the pem file.

Comment: I understand that you believe you need to change the permissions on the private key PEM file, and am aware of the circumstances (on Unix) that would require this... but am asking you to explain *why* you believe this is necessary on your Windows system, because it stands to reason that what you are attempting is based on an incorrect prior assumption, somewhere.  What error messages and troubleshooting steps led you to the conclusion that permissions on the key file are the cause of the problem you are trying to solve?